# IE 11 crashes on setting required level in dynamics CRM 2013 hosted

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dynamics-crm-2013

Internet Explorer crashes whenever I try to setRequiredLevel for a field in dynamics CRM 2013 hosted org. Below is the code which is causing issue.

```
try {
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_cvv") != null) {Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_cvv").setRequiredLevel("required");}
} catch (e) {
alert(e.toString());
}
```

I have tried using setTimeOut but it did not worked. 
There is no debug information about this. I have updated IE 11 to 11.0.3 but it also went in vain.

Comment: have you tried to disable your function, and checked if it crashes again.
i believe it must be something else on your form, an `IFRAME` etc.

have you tried the above code on some other entity field. ?

Comment: your whole browser crashes?  or CRM just alerts you of an error?  DotNetPro is right, this kind of thing is __highly unlikely__ to cause your whole browser to crash.

Comment: CRM form crashes and CRM is reloaded.

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar this snippet of the code is correct, I just tried it in my own CRM Org and it worked fine.  You should post the whole method that it is a part of and if there are no clear issues with it, the best way to verify that this specific code is causing the problem would be to comment out these 5 lines and see if you still have the same issue.  More likely it is an issue somewhere else in the js library.